# Cannot Open Rails console without getting circular argument warning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console

Whenever I type in rails console into terminal (I'm in the root of my program), I get this:

```
/Users/TURNIPZ/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:270: warning: circular argument reference - now
/Users/TURNIPZ/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': cannot load such file -- test/unit/testcase (LoadError)
from /Users/TURNIPZ/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
from /Users/TURNIPZ/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/TURNIPZ/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /Users/TURNIPZ/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/test_case.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/TURNIPZ/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /Users/TURNIPZ/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
from /Users/TURNIPZ/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/TURNIPZ/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /Users/TURNIPZ/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/console/app.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/TURNIPZ/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /Users/TURNIPZ/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
from /Users/TURNIPZ/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/TURNIPZ/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /Users/TURNIPZ/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:304:in `initialize_console'
from /Users/TURNIPZ/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:152:in `load_console'
from /Users/TURNIPZ/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:27:in `start'
from /Users/TURNIPZ/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /Users/TURNIPZ/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

How do I get rid of this and be able to use rails console? I think it has something to do with this https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/rails-console-not-fully-loading. I'm a complete beginner, so I'll probably need a step by step guide to fixing the problem. How do I add

```
gem 'test unit'
```

to my gemfile.

Comment: Why are you using ActiveSupport 3.2.13? That's three years old, but you're using it with close to the latest Ruby. You're following an ancient tutorial using ancient versions -- you're going to have to expect some problems. Consider updating to a current version of Rails, add some Google Fu and you should be in better shape.

Comment: is it better to always go with the latest? I was trying to learn rails 3. is it better just to move on and go to rails 4?

Comment: The version of Ruby you're using didn't exist when Rails 3.2 was current, and is the reason you ran into the problem you're posting about. Rails 5 is due for release within the next couple of months. If you're learning to learn, go with whatever is current. If you're learning because you have to maintain an old Rails 3.2 app, then learn 3.2.

Comment: okay thank you. I'll try to learn rails 4 then. thank you.